# How to call an API twice if there is an error occurred?

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-promise

I have an internal API that I would like to post data. Depends on some cases, I am seeing errors. So what I would like to do is to call it again if there is an error occurred.

What I did was to create a counter to pass it to the function and call the function recursively as below. This gives me the error as below:

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)`

Here is how I call the function:

```
....
private RETRY_API = 1;
....

 try {
    await this.callAPI(request, this.RETRY_API);
} catch (error) {
    console.log('error', error);
}
```

This program never comes to the catch block above.

And here is my actual function that I call the API:

```
private async callAPI(request, retry) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       someService.postApiRequest('api/url', request, async(err: any, httpCode: number, data) => {
     if (this.RETRY_API == 2) {
         return reject(err);
      } else if (err) {
          this.callAPI(request, retry);
          this.RETRY_API++;
      } else if ( httpCode !== 200 ) {
          this.RETRY_API = 2;
          // some stuff
      } else {
           this.RETRY_API = 2;
           // some stuff
           return resolve(data);
      }
   });
  })
}
```

Not sure what I am missing. If there is a better way to call the API twice if an error occurred, that would be great if you let me know.

Comment: Seems like it's failing in the `callAPI` function if the catch is never being called. Are you getting any thing on `err`?

Comment: Currently, not getting err since I test it locally. So I override the `err` and try to simulate the error case. In this case, I have an error. Then I get the error message I posted above.

Comment: I'm surprised that `someService.postApiRequest()` takes an `async` callback as its third parameter. Ordinarily, a service with a callback would call the callback synchronously.  Probably, either the service can return a promise (so you don't need to wrap it in a new promise), or the callback shouldn't be qualified as async.  Once we get that sorted, there's a pretty simple answer, involving a recursive call in the catch block.

Comment: @danh, that async is for other stuff only. we can remove that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's organize a little differently. First, a promise-wrapper for the api...

```
private async callAPI(request) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    someService.postApiRequest('api/url', request,(err: any, httpCode: number, data) => {
      err ? reject(err) : resolve(data);
    });
  });
}
```

A utility function to use setTimeout with a promise...

```
async function delay(t) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t));
}
```

Now, a function that calls and retries with delay...

```
private async callAPIWithRetry(request, retryCount=2, retryDelay=2000) {
  try {
    return await callAPI(request);
  } catch (error) {
    if (retryCount <= 0) throw err;
    await delay(retryDelay);
    return callAPIWithRetry(request, retryCount-1, retryDelay);
  }
}
```

If you can't force a failure on the api to test the error path some other way, you can at least try this...

```
private async callAPIWithRetry(request, retryCount=2, retryDelay=2000) {
  try {
    // I hate to do this, but the only way I can test the error path is to change the code here to throw an error
    // return await callAPI(request);
    await delay(500);
    throw("mock error");
  } catch (error) {
    if (retryCount <= 0) throw err;
    await delay(retryDelay);
    return callAPIWithRetry(request, retryCount-1, retryDelay);
  }
}
```

Comment: This actually works and better approach. Thank you, @danh!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to add `return await` to the beginning of the line `this.callAPI(request, retry);` in `callAPI` function.

Similarly there are some condition blocks that doesn't resolve or reject the promise. While it might work okay, it's considered bad practice. You want to either resolve or reject a promise.

Comment: In this case, I think it's doesn't matter if I add `return await` or not. Even it's added, still getting the same error.

Comment: You need to return something here too `this.RETRY_API = 2;`

Comment: Basically, whether it fixes your issue immediately or not, make sure all the control blocks return eventually. Otherwise your promise will stay stuck in pending state. Without that fix, you may not make a progress towards a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've accomplished calling an API a second time when I received an error by using [axios' interceptors functions](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors).

Here is a code snippet you can review:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
    // function called on a successful response 2xx
    function (response) {
        return response;
    },
    // function called on an error response ( not 2xx )
    async function (error) {
        const request = error.config as AxiosRequestConfig;
        
        // request is original API call
        
        // change something about the call and try again
        // request.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer DIFFERENT_TOKEN`;
        // return axios(request)
        
        // or Call a different API
        // const new_data = await axios.get(...).then(...)
        // return new_data
        
        // all else fails return the original error
        return Promise.reject(error)
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
if (this.RETRY_API == 2)
```

with

```
if (this.RETRY_API > 1)
```